# Calling C# DLL that contains WCF web service from Excel

Tags: c#, wcf, excel, com

This question has been asked previously but my circumstances are slightly different.

I have an Excel add-in that we distribute to our users that now needs to connect to a downstream system. That downstream system have provided me a WCF webservice to do this with so I designed a C# DLL wrapper that I could expose through COM that would communicate to the WCF webservice and return the results through a COM interface to Excel.

I have Excel talking to the COM wrapper fine now, though I have had to revert to Framework 3.5 for the DLL for reasons I have yet to fathom to do with Excel and .NET runtime versions. The problem is that when I call the COM exposed method in the C# DLL I get an error returned saying "Could not find default endpoint..."

This error seems to be because the service configuration is not being picked up, obviously because I have no app.config as this is purely a stand alone DLL. I could put the config in Excel.exe.config I'm sure but that isn't an option as making changes to users Excel configuration will not be allowed. And I cannot hard code values into the C# code as we will need different environments configurable with an external config file.

Basically I need to have a config file that I can distribute with my DLL and the excel add in, so that when excel calls my COM exposed C# DLL, it then also picks up the Config file and loads the WCF endpoint configuration from there. I know how to read a config file in using ConfigurationManager but I cannot figure out how to let .NET know that this config file contains the EndPoint information for the WCF services. The only solution I have found so far involves overriding the default app domain configuration loading so that .NET loads your manually specified file for app.config default settings, but all the solutions I have foudn for this online use .NET 4.5 objects and code, when I am limited to .NET 3.5.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider confugurating your WCF client endpoint in the code rather than in config file.
For more details please see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx

Comment: I can't do this unfortunately as I mentioned above, I need to be able to specify different environments - ie DEV, UAT, Production so I cannot hard code values.

Comment: but you can read then from whenever you want now. For example additional config file